# hook_menu() wildcard at start

Tags: php, drupal-7

Working on a hook_menu() function that i got working fine with the following code:

```
function mymodule_menu(){
    $items = array();
    $items['assessment/%'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'mymodule_assessment_page',
        'page arguments' => 'array(1),
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'file' => 'pages/mymodule.assessment.inc',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
}
```

However when i try the following (after clearing cache etc) i get a page not found error.

```
function mymodule_menu(){
    $items = array();
    $items['%/assessment'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'mymodule_assessment_page',
        'page arguments' => 'array(0),
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'file' => 'pages/mymodule.assessment.inc',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
}
```

Ive searched google and i see no mention of not being able to put a path wildcard at the front of the url.

Can anyone notice anything im doing wrong here?
Or is it a case of drupal not supporting paths beginning with wildcards.

Anyhelp will be massively appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use the wildcard as the first component. If you look at the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) for `hook_menu()` you will see the following:

> Wildcards in Paths Simple Wildcards
>
> Wildcards within paths also work with integer substitution. For
>   example, your module could register path 'my-module/%/edit':
>
> ```
> $items['my-module/%/edit'] = array(
>    'page callback' => 'mymodule_abc_edit',
>    'page arguments' => array(1),   
>   );
> ```
>
> When path 'my-module/foo/edit' is requested, integer 1 will be
>   replaced with 'foo' and passed to the callback function. **Note that
>   wildcards may not be used as the first component.**

Comment: thanks for the confirmation, i always get lost in the documentation, i tend to scan it, i should start reading it more thoroughly. Thanks again